# No suitable driver hibernate postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I have a transitime app which is maven project. When i do

```
mvn package -D maven.test.skip=true
```

it creates some jars in transitime/target folder. 
It writes during packaging, that postgresql is included:

```
[INFO] Including postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4 in the shaded jar.
```

My postgresql version is 9.1-19, so driver version is fine. i checked it.

then i run one of jars with config files, with i suppose proper database name and credentials and urls. 
and i get:

```
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@72337297 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt 

exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

It is stated that this problem is with wrong connection url or no driver. 
I have configured in postgresql_hibernate.xml:

```
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      org.postgresql.Driver
   </property>
```

It seems to me that maven compilation doesnt add postgresql drivers, but maven states that are included. I am new to maven but i don't know how to check or force including drivers in project. Or maybe something else for newbie is here i am missing. 
When i unzipped jar that i am executing it includes org/postgresql.Driver.class.

==edit
jdbc url is: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname`

Comment: "No suitable driver" can either indicate a missing jar file or an invalid JDBC URL. What is the JDBC URL you are using?

Comment: You should put the JDBC driver jar file in <server>/lib. And please add the maven file for details look.

Comment: jdbc url is jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname also i dont use server, i run single jar file with java -jar command